# Connect to AnyDesk from command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line-interface

I'm trying to connect with AnyDesk to a remote computer using a script.

I tried to execute the following command in Prompt as described in the [documentation](https://support.anydesk.com/Command_Line_Interface):

```
echo "password" | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" "anydesk_id" --with-password
```

Anydesk starts correctly and start connecting with the given id, but the password is not considered and I have to manually insert it.

I'm using AnyDesk 6.1 on Windows 10. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a .bat script and used the following and it worked. The only difference is no quotes around the anydesk_id or password.

```
echo PASSWORD | "C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" anydesk_id --with-password
```

Comment: Thank you :) Actually there is no problem leaving quotes around anydesk_id, but the quotes around the password are a problem because echo prints them as well.

Comment: Also worked with new version. Thanks.